# AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. The configuration object is missing required auth properties

Tags: electron, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I am making an electron desktop app with Amplify. When I try to sign up a user I get the below error which seems common for amplify:

> VM9640 ConsoleLogger.js:125 [ERROR] 00:14.280 AuthError -
> Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
> The configuration object is missing required auth properties.

1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
   See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information
2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.

My main.js looks like below:

```
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain, shell} = require('electron');
const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin';
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const { Amplify, Auth } = require('aws-amplify');
const awsmobile = require('./aws-exports.js');

console.log(awsmobile)

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
Auth.configure(awsmobile);

let win;

function createWindow() { ...
```

I have tried adding configuration for auth, my preload.js looks like below for exposing globally:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('Amplify', { 
  Auth: Amplify.Auth,
  awsmobile: awsmobile,
  signUp: async (username, password, email, phone_number, name) => {
    try {
      const { user } = await Amplify.Auth.signUp({
        username,
        password,
        attributes: {
          email,
          phone_number,
          name
        },
      });
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

});
```

And my sign up function is below:

```
async function signUp() {
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const phone_number = document.getElementById('phone_number').value;
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value;

  try {
    const user = await Amplify.signUp({
      username,
      password,
      attributes: {
        email,
        phone_number,
        name,
      },
    });
    alert('Sign up successful');
    console.log('User:', user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error signing up:', error);
    alert('Sign up failed. Please check your inputs and try again.');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const signupButton = document.getElementById('signup-button');
  signupButton.addEventListener('click', signUp);
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const backButton = document.getElementById('back-button');

  backButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    history.back(); // Go back to the previous page
  });
});
```

I have tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json but the error persists, I have also added Auth configuration to main.js. I tried adding:

```
npm i @aws-amplify/core --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/storage --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/interactions --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/auth --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/api --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/analytics --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/xr --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.